# Getting Blank Screen for Perl CGI Script

Tags: perl, cgi, dbi

I am getting blank screen for the below Perl CGI Script on the web page.
Script is getting executed fine on the terminal, but when I run it from the web browser it is blank. Please help.

This works when I move the Web Content to the top of the page. Basically whatever content I put after the DB connection is not getting displayed on the web browser.

OS : Unix
Apache2 Web Server

Note: The script has execute permission.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use DBI;
use CGI;

print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";

# Simple HTML code follows
my $driver= "Oracle";
my $dsn = "DBI:$driver:sid=xxxxx;host=xxxxx;port=1521";
my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn,'xxxx','xxxx');

#print $dbh;

my $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE ROWNUM <= 10");
$sth->execute;

print "<html> <head>\n";
print "<title>Hello, world!</title>";
print "</head>\n";
print "<body>\n";
print "<h1>Hello, world!</h1>\n";
print "<p>The Details  are as follows:</p>\n";
print "<table cols=5 border=1>\n";
print "<tr>\n";
print "<th>ACTION</th>\n";
print "<th>ALARM_TEXT</th>\n";
print "<th>ALARM_SEV</th>\n";
print "<th>EMS_NAME</th>\n";
print "</tr>";

while(  my $ref = $sth->fetchrow_hashref() ) {
        print "<tr>\n";
        print "<td>", $ref->{'ACTION'}, "</td>\n";
        print "<td>", $ref->{'ALARM_TEXT'}, "</td>\n";
        print "<td>", $ref->{'ALARM_SEV'}, "</td>\n";
        print "<td>", $ref->{'EMS_NAME'}, "</td>\n";
        print "</tr>\n";
}
print "</table>\n";
print "<h1>Hello, world!</h1>\n";
print "</body> </html>\n";
```

Comment: Well, what's failing?

Comment: I have updated the Question. Please check. I am getting blank screen. If I put some content above the DB connection, then those things are getting printed on the web page.

Comment: What did you do to debug? Did you even check for error messages? We can't help you fix the problem until it's been identified!

Comment: *"Basically whatever content I put after the DB connection is not getting displayed on the web browser."* - my guess is that the DB connection fails so that `$dbh` is undefined and subsequent use of `$dbh` in `$dbh->prepare` will cause a fatal error and the process to exit. But for details look at the error messages you should find in the error log of Apache.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich : Yes You are right.  
Error in Apache log are

[Fri May 18 04:51:31 2018] [error] [client 159.166.29.10] DBI connect('sid=xxxxx;host=xxxxx;port=1521,'xxxxx',...) failed: ERROR OCIEnvNlsCreate. Check ORACLE_HOME (Linux) env var  or PATH (Windows) and or NLS settings, permissions, etc. at /var/www/cgi-bin/Test.pl line 27
[Fri May 18 04:51:31 2018] [error] [client 159.166.29.10] Can't call method "prepare" on an undefined value at /var/www/cgi-bin/Test.pl line 31.

But I have no idea why it is not picking the ORACLE_HOME. Where can I set it, so that it will be permanent ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it by adding the below line to the httdd.conf file.

```
SetEnv ORACLE_HOME /oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0.4/db_1
```